# Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - requestFiltering

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho aplicação que permite fazer upload com arquivos grandes.

Já subi meu site na hospedagem, tento navegar na página principal e recebo erro:

```
Detailed Error Information:

Module             RequestFilteringModule
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler            ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code         0x80070021
Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path.
                   This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.
                   Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"),
                   or set explicitly by a location tag with 
                   overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File        \\?\E:\Domains\meusite.com.br\wwwroot\web.config
```

Veja imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o arquivo completo [web.config](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matmiranda/04b9572363c6dddba799330e6383c700/raw/09b84fdd7fa7bf26b65e69ae254388bd99e69f02/Web.config):

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
    <!--<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />-->
    <!-- 100 * 1024 * 1024 = 104857600 bytes = (100MB) -->
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Rodando aplicação localmente funciona muito bem, agora pela hospedagem não funciona.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda, pois provavelmente você não tem acessos ao IIS, mas veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Já tentei na resposta aceita, continua o mesmo problema. Me parece que na resposta aceita, deve fazer no servidor dele.

Comment: Sim, tem que ser no servidor onde está hospedado, por isso que imaginei que não serviria pra você.

Comment: Matheus, tenta criar a configuração em um arquivo ini, chamando-o de "user.ini" ou ".user.ini" que é comum ser a configuração personalizada do iis para seu software em servidores compatilhados de hospedagem.